# dimple.js: unable to create stacked bar using two series

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I am trying to create a stack bar chart by adding two series separately.  See example here: http://jsbin.com/tonesoretu/1/watch?js,output

As you can see, this does not stack the two series.  It does work if use a single data set and the category is the 'group' field, but unfortunately, i am not getting the data in that manner.  Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to combine the datasets if you want to do this in dimple.  You can combine them like this:

http://jsbin.com/laniyigiru/1/edit?js,output

Comment: thanks.  would be nice if dimple could be enhanced such that this works w/   with two distinct calls to addSeries...more intuitive and less conditional code can be written if so.